# Formatting of saving result into file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I executed a JDBC request and save result in to a file and want to use that file into CSV Data set config for paramerization

I have successfully save results in to file but not able to handle the formatting of file i.e. the gap between columns and their values.

[image].

Should I apply any SQL statement if yes 
please provide the solution

Comment: Jmeter is designed for running load-testing against a server, not running a single JDBC request...

Answer (score 0):

Most/All db have built in functions to trim whitespace

- MySQL: TRIM( ), RTRIM( ), LTRIM( )
- Oracle: RTRIM( ), LTRIM( )
- SQL Server: RTRIM(  ), LTRIM( )

So if this doesn't work

```
select trim(columnName) from some_table
```

try

```
rtrim(ltrim(columnName)) from some_table
```

Using those SQL functions to format SQL data so its clean from the start is fastest & cleanest option in my opinion. That said, if you cant do that, There are other options. You could do a replace() in your select.. you could use beanshell.. you could modify your seperator in the jmeter CSV file so instead of just `","` it is something like `",/t"` or `", "`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beanshell language to get rid of extra spaces like:

1. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) after the PostProcessor which does the file writing or as a child of the relevant sampler. You can also use [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) but it will appear in your test results.
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   File myFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.csv");
   String source = FileUtils.readFileToString(myFile);
   String withoutSpaces = source.replaceAll(" ","");
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myFile,withoutSpaces);
   ```

   The above code will remove all occurences of whitespaces from the given file. Theoretically you can do it on-the-fly without reading and overwriting the file but we need to know a little bit more about your script to suggest the exact solution. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on using Beanshell in your JMeter test.